# force a global variable to be initialized before a certain static field

Tags: c++, arrays, static, global-variables

I want the global variable's initialization (#A) to be called before initialization of static field (#B).

Currently, some static fields are initialized before global variable.

**GridUtil.h**

```
class GridUtil{
   static Vec4* bPtr_;  //will be filled
   static void initGridCalculationCache();
   static class _init   //helper class
    {
        public:
        _init() { 
        static_iniAll(); 
        }
    } _initializer;

}
```

**GridUtil.cpp**

```
#include "GridUtil.h"
GridUtil::_init GridUtil::_initializer;// (Edit: This line is just added, thank Dietmar Kühl.)
Vec4 b[24];                      //#A executed 3rd : No, this should be the first.
Vec4* GridUtil::bPtr_=b;         //#B executed 1st
void GridUtil::initGridCalculationCache() {
    //.... fill GridUtil::bPtr_ using complex computation //#C executed 2nd
}
```

**Result**

From debugging, the execution order of above code is:-

```
B->C->A
```

But I want :-

```
A->B->C
```

I noticed that if "Vec4" is replaced by "int", the execution order will be:-

```
A->B->C
```

**The objective** is to set value of elements in the array (bPtr_) using a static function (initGridCalculationCache) that would be called automatically (helped by class _init).

If it is not possible, what is a correct way to do it?

Comment: Did you try to declare your global variable in GridUtil.cpp before including GridUtil.h, or declaring it static?

Comment: You can see that for global informations : https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order.

Comment: @wasthishelpful Thank! That is the correct answer, you can post as answer if you wish.

Comment: @javaLover Which one? Moving the position or making it static?

Comment: wasthishelpful's comment can solve my problem "declare your global variable in GridUtil.cpp before including GridUtil.h" ; N0un - thank for a great link

Comment: You need to change your program design so that you don't have any static initialization order dependencies. And that's that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The four obvious solutions in order of preference are:

1. Do **not** have global or `static` member variables to start with! These tend to create a large amount of problems, doubly so in systems utilizing concurrency.
2. Use `constexpr` objects as these get initialized during compilation time. There are, obviously, some constraints on what can be done but the compiler would verify that objects are initialized in the proper order.
3. Within a translation unit objects with static live time are initialized from top to bottom. That is, using the proper order if variable definition may achieve the desired order. There is, however, no portable approach ordering varriable initialization across translation units.
4. When there are dependencies on initialization between objects from different translation units the correct order can be guaranteed using function local `static` objects to which a reference is returned: these will be constructed upon first access.

Comment: "3. Within a translation unit objects with static live time are initialized from top to bottom." OP's code seems that the objects defined in one TU aren't initialized from top to bottom?

Comment: @songyuanyao  Yes, OP's code isn't initialized A->B->C .  But after I do as  wasthishelpful's advice (move #include), it is now correct.  I have edited the question to make it clear.  Dietmar Kühl's description is consistent with the result.

Comment: @javaLover So it's not always from top to bottom, depends on some other things (like the position of the relevant class definition etc) ? I just want to confirm about that.

Comment: @songyuanyao  I think it is top to bottom, notice the #include.  My wrong code add #include before everything else, so in .cpp perspective, static_iniAll(); is called before #A.  ......   static_iniAll() is called at the line "static class _init" in .h   ....... I think it is top to bottom for every .cpp ( not for .h)

Comment: @songyuanyao: note that the initialization of the pointer `GridUtil::bPtr` has no side-effect and it can't be observed when it actually is initialized. Since the compiler does know the value already at link time it is free to give it a value ahead of time: there is no way to determine whether it was initialized before `b` (trying to read its value, e.g., from a constructor of an object placed right before it would result in undefined behavior).

Comment: @javaLover As far as I can see, the compiler you used doesn't tend to initialize objects from top to bottom. Moving the position of class definition just make it impossible to initialize the class member at first. I want to know why in 1st case. Might be the difference between global variable and static member variable? Or like other's answer said, non-class type will be iniatialized firstly?

Comment: @javaLover: note that `_initializer` is nowhere defined in the snippet you posted. Its presence in the class definition is only a declaration not a definition. Unless it is defined somewhere, it shouldn't be constructed, either! The position of the definition would specify the relative order of its initialization within a translation unit.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl  Op! Sorry, I will edit the question.  You have sharp eyes :).

Answer (score 0):

The order is rather simple, POD are initialized by copying them from the .DATA section of your binary to RAM. Classes are initialized at runtime by their ctor. Therefore POD will allways be initialized befor any class with a ctor as long as they are in the same static area. If you use DLL/SO everything gets funny.

The order of initialization is undefined. There are no guarantees for anything. If you explicitly need an special order, initialize your static vars in an init function.